# How to check when request was send

Tags: php

I'm running several requests (A, B, C, ...) and they are queued to happen sequentially: B waits for A to complete, C waits for B, and so on. I want to get the timestamp of the moment when they *get into the queue*. I can get the timestamp of the request when it's *actually happening*, that is, the time of B when A is already done - `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` gives me that, but that's not what I want. I'd like to have the precise times of getting into the queue, no matter when they arrive to the server.

Sending timestamp as an additional GET parameter doesn't seem safe enough because it can be forged on client side. Is there another way?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say that request A, B and C are requested _"at the same time"_, yet you want to use the time, when the requests are made, to order them. At least that what I assume when reading your question.That is either impossible, or I misunderstood your question. Whatever it is, your question could use some clarification.

Comment: Requested at the same time I mean the PHP file is requested 5 times in separate tabs

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. He means "requested at approximately the same time".

Comment: Well, I hope I understood the OPs intention. I can absolutely understand the guy saying "unclear".

Comment: That is exactly what i mean, thanks for edit

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

var_dump($info);
echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', 
$info['url'], "\n";
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I mean PHP script request (user request to my page PHP script) not curl, sorry if my question was unclear